# start service remotely on windows 2003~2012

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

My boss has aksked me to grant access to ~5 various services on XXX-hundred servers (2003~20012).

I've tried to setup SDDL on each service (I've been testing BITS service on my particular account), even I setup access for my account: example command::

```
sc sdset BITS D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)
(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)
(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;**[startStopListSettings]**;;;**MY-SID**)S:
(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

even I created this new entry I'm not able to start/stop service using SC from another computer as non-admin user.

What else i need to do to allow non-administrator user access to start service on remote computer?
does anyone have any solution ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to edit service permissions I have created 3 functions get/add/remove:

```
    #Requires -version 3 
    #####################
    # Cod info      :Set Service Rights on remote computer. By this script you can set rights on service on many computers modding SDDL remotely.
    #                You need - service name  - object SID you want to add/remove access and computer name(s)
    # V             :1.3.2.0
    # D             :01-06-2017
    # Author        : stackoverflow.com - gsky
    # INFO          :All credits go to the autor of this script. No changes without confirmation
    # Compatibiliy  :Powershell 3 and up (.net 3.5 and up)
    # Supported     :From Windows 2003 to 2016
    #keywords:      : Windows, Wintel, Service, Remote,Add Rights, Remove Rights
    #####################



    function Get-MGServiceRights 
    {
    <#
        .DESCRIPTION
        Gets Service rights from (remote)Computer(s)

        .PARAMETER computername
        Specifies the computername.

        .PARAMETER ServiceName
        Specifies the Service Name

        .EXAMPLE
        Get-MGServiceRights -computerName  testComputer123 -ServiceName BITS

        .NOTES
        version 1.3.2.0 
        #>
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$computerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$ServiceName
    )
    foreach ($computer in $computerName)
    {
        $msgError = $null
        $Output = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            Computer = $computer
            ServiceName = $ServiceName
            Acl = $null
        }
        $SC_CMD = 'sc.exe'
        $arg1 = "\\$computer"
        $arg2 = 'sdshow'
        $arg3 = "$ServiceName"


        [string[]]$queryResult = & $SC_CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3

        if ($queryResult[0] -like "*FAILED *")
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $queryResult.count; $i++)
            {
                $msgError += $queryResult[$i] | ? -filter { $_ -ne '' }
            }
            $Output.acl = $msgError -replace '\[SC\]\sOpenS.[A-Za-z]*\s', "GET: "
        }
        else
        {
            $Output.acl = ($queryResult | ? -filt { $_ -ne '' }) -replace ""
        }
        $Output
    }
}


    function Add-MGServiceRights
    {<#
        .DESCRIPTION
        Adds Service rights - on remote Computer(s) 

        .PARAMETER computername
        Specifies the computername.

        .PARAMETER ServiceName
        Specifies the Service Name

        .PARAMETER objectSID
        Specifies the SID of an object you want to add (fe. account's  sid is: S-1-5-00-0000000-000000000-00000000) 

        .PARAMETER ACL
        Specifies the level of rights - you can select one from three options: Control (start/stop/query status of service), List (query status of service), FullControl (full conotrol)


        .EXAMPLE
        Add-MGServiceRights -computerName  testComputer123,testComputer124 -ServiceName BITS -objectSID S-1-5-00-0000000-000000000-00000000 -ACL FullControl

        .NOTES
        version 1.3.2.0 
        #>
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$computerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$ServiceName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 2)]
        [system.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$objectSID,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 3)]
        [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute("Control", "Read", "FullControl")]
        [string]$ACL = "Control"
    )

    begin
    {

        $myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
        $myWindowsPrincipal = new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
        $adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
        if (!($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))) { Write-Error "Script Requires ELEVATION!. Run console as an Administrator"; break }

    }
    process
    {
        switch ($acl)
        {

            Read {
                $permissions = "CCLCSWLOCRRC"
            }
            FullControl {
                $permissions = "CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO"
            }
            default
            {
                $permissions = "CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC"
            }
        }


        $scRightsForNewObject = ("(A;;$permissions;;;$($objectSID.value))").ToUpper()

        foreach ($computer in $computerName)
        {
            $msgError = $null
            $Output = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                Computer = $computer
                Account = $objectSID
                ServiceName = $ServiceName
                CommandResponse = $null
            }
            try
            {
                $ScriptResult = (Get-MGServiceRights -computerName $computer -ServiceName $ServiceName).acl


            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Error $error[0].Exception.Message
                break
            }
            if ($ScriptResult -like "*Failed*")
            {
                $Output.CommandResponse = "ADD: $ScriptResult"
            }

            else
            {
                if ($ScriptResult -like "*$scRightsForNewObject*")
                { $Output.CommandResponse = "ADD: Object already exists with same level of rights." }
                else
                {
                    $SDDLtoADD = $ScriptResult -replace "[S]\:", "$scRightsForNewObject`S:"

                    $SC_CMD = 'sc.exe'
                    $arg1 = "\\$computer"
                    $arg2 = 'sdset'
                    $arg3 = $ServiceName
                    $arg4 = $SDDLtoADD

                    [string[]]$queryResult = & $SC_CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

                    $output.CommandResponse = ($queryResult | ? -filter { $_ -ne '' })
                    $output.CommandResponse = $output.CommandResponse -replace '\[SC\]', "ADD:"

                    if ($queryResult[0] -like "*FAILED *")
                    {
                        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $queryResult.count; $i++)
                        {
                            ($msgError += $queryResult[$i] | ? -filter { $_ -ne '' }) | out-null
                        }
                        $Output.CommandResponse = $msgError -replace '\[SC\]\sOpenS.[A-Za-z]*\s', 'ADD: '
                    }
                }


            }
            $Output
        }
    }
}



    function Remove-MGServiceRights
    {<#
        .DESCRIPTION
        Removes Service rights - on remote Computer(s) 

        .PARAMETER computername
        Specifies the computername.

        .PARAMETER ServiceName
        Specifies the Service Name

        .PARAMETER objectSID
        Specifies the SID of an object you want to add (fe. account's xxxxxx sid is: S-1-5-00-0000000-000000000-00000000) 


        .EXAMPLE
        Remove-MGServiceRights -computerName  testComputer123,testComputer124 -ServiceName BITS -objectSID S-1-5-00-0000000-000000000-00000000

        .NOTES
        version 1.3.2.0 
        #>
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$computerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string]$ServiceName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 2)]
        [system.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$objectSID


    )

    begin
    {

        $myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
        $myWindowsPrincipal = new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
        $adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
        if (!($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))) { Write-Error "Script Requires ELEVATION!. Run console as an Administrator"; break }

    }
    process
    {
        foreach ($computer in $computerName)
        {
            $msgError = $null
            $Output = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                Computer = $computer
                Account = $objectSID
                ServiceName = $ServiceName
                CommandResponse = $null
            }
            try
            {
                $ScriptResult = (Get-MGServiceRights -computerName $computer -ServiceName $ServiceName).acl

            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Error $error[0].Exception.Message
                break
            }
            if ($ScriptResult -like "*Failed*")
            {
                $Output.CommandResponse = "REMOVE: $ScriptResult"
                $Output
            }

            else
            {
                $found = $false

                $ScriptResult -split "\)" | foreach {

                    if ($_ -notlike "*$objectSID*")
                    {
                        $newAcl_ += $_ + ")"
                    }
                    elseif ($_ -like "*$objectSID*")
                    {
                        $found = $true
                    }
                }


                if ($found)
                {
                    $SDDLtoADD = $newAcl_.Remove($newAcl_.length - 1, 1)

                    $SC_CMD = 'sc.exe'
                    $arg1 = "\\$computer"
                    $arg2 = 'sdset'
                    $arg3 = $ServiceName
                    $arg4 = $SDDLtoADD
                    [string[]]$queryResult = & $SC_CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

                    $output.CommandResponse = ($queryResult | ? -filter { $_ -ne '' })
                    $output.CommandResponse = $output.CommandResponse -replace '\[SC\]', "REMOVE:"

                    if ($queryResult[0] -like "*FAILED *")
                    {
                        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $queryResult.count; $i++)
                        {
                            ($msgError += $queryResult[$i] | ? -filter { $_ -ne '' }) | out-null
                        }
                        $Output.CommandResponse = $msgError -replace '\[SC\]\sOpenS.[A-Za-z]*\s', 'REMOVE: '
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $Output.CommandResponse = "REMOVE: Object Not Found"
                }


                $Output
            }
        }
    }
}
```